# Why does mouseover on "full site" link change the mouse icon incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, bug

In the mobile version of the site there is an option in the footer to switch back to full site. However, mouseover on this link (and *only* on this link) shows a "type text here" mouse icon instead of the pointing finger as usual.

This happens both with Firefox and IE.

In the (somewhat misleading) screenshot below the arrow mouse icon is shown incorrectly, as a bug/feature of Ubuntu's screenshot program. The icon displayed on screen is the "type text here" as I stated before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can confirm this with latest Chrome on Windows, but again can't take a screenshot that shows it.